# Nginx configuration for shortlink service: Rewrite if not file

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

Some time ago I developed a shortlink service (like goo.gl).

Shortlinks in the browsers addressbar are displayed as `example.com/Lg1Q`

Recently I migrated from Lighty to Nginx, due to performance benefits.
In Lighttpd I used

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
    "^/(.*)(\?.*)?$" => "/index.php?fwd=$1"
)
```

to hand over the "Lg1Q" part from the URL to the index.php script.

The index.php script processes the not-file-part from the URL as follows:

```
if ( !empty( $myUrl ) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== '/index.php' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== '/index.html' && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !$

        $query = htmlspecialchars( str_replace("fwd=","", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) );
        require_once 'src/clsForwardURL.class.php';
        $myForward = new clsForwardURL();
        $url = $myForward->fForwardURL( $query );
        $url = ( $url[0]['su_longurl'] );
        echo header( 'location:'.$url );


}//end if
```

I tried to rebuild the rewrite rule from Lighttpd to Nginx syntax like:

```
rewrite "^/(.*)(\?.*)?$" /index.php?fwd=$1;
```

After that, I inserted this rule subsequently in the `location ~ \.php` block and the `location /`  block of the nginx host container in /etc/nginx/sites-available.

Unfortunally in both cases the browser showed a '404' or a '500' error.

My question is:
How can I properly setup the rewrite rule for the 'shortlink' purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rewrite` in the `location /` block will rewrite everything - not just your short URIs. You could qualify the rewrite operation using a `try_files` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?fwd=$1 last;
}
```

Notice that the query string component is not part of the normalised URI used by the `rewrite` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

You can simplify the above further, if you modify the PHP code to accept a leading `/` in the `fwd` parameter, in which case you could use:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?fwd=$uri;
}
```

Comment: The first example in @Richard Smith answer above did the trick for my script.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a rewrite, the whole capture logic can be in the root location itself, e.g:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
      ...
}

# using a name variable instead of $1
location ~ ^/(?<short_url>.*)$ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?fwd=$short_url;
}
```

Comment: There is no `?` and query string in the *normalised URI* considered by the regular expression location. The sequence `(\?.*)?` is redundant.

Comment: That's correct, that specific part is unnecessary (I updated my answer).