# setting up rewrite rules in nginx for location rewrites

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I am a total noob to nginx. I am trying to set up some rules in nginx for location rewrites. What I am trying to achieve is this:

```
1. no change
https://hello.domain.com/index.php --> https://hello.domain.com/index.php

2. subdomain needs to be included
https://hello.domain.com --> https://hello.domain.com/index.php?sub=hello

3. subdomain & folder structure needs to be included
https://hello.domain.com/dir1/15 --> https://hello.domain.com/index.php?sub=hello&path=dir1/15

4. requests to certain directories ( images, css, etc... ) need to be ignored
https://hello.domain.com/images/logo.png --> https://hello.domain.com/images/logo.png
```

I am able to get the subdomain into a variable $sub with this

```
server_name ~^(?<sub>.+)\.domain\.com$;
```

I tried to use the location directive but it only works for #2 and #3 in the list

```
location / {
        rewrite ^ /index.php?sub=$sub&path=$request_uri;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: You could use `try_files` to take care of case #4, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448911/nginx-configuration-for-shortlink-service-rewrite-if-not-file/42468423#42468423) for guidance.

Comment: or maybe this: `if ($request_uri !~ "^/(?:images|css)") { rewrite ^ "/index.php?path=$request_uri&sub=$sub" last; }`

Comment: I have been reading that using `if` conditionals is not recommended

Comment: this should work also for the `location` scope, since makes an internal redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you forward:

```
server_name ~^(?<sub>.+)\.domain\.com$;

location /images {
    # You can put this code in a snippet file and than include
    # it with e.g. `include assets.conf;` so you can use more
    # folders with longest prefix match blocks, which are more
    # efficient than regex blocks.

    # Tell the browser to cache this for one day
    expires 1d;

    # Just give the resource
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location /index.php {
    # PHP stuff goes here
}

location / {
    rewrite ^ /index.php?sub=$sub&path=$uri last;
}
```